# Lazy load Angular component from database

Tags: angular, typescript

Problem: dashboard component rendering arbitrary widgets stored in a database.
I managed to get it working somewhat, and wonder if there are any less hacky ways to get it done.

**Here's what I did (and just in case also how I got there):**

Lazy loading from a file can be very simple, something like this seems to work well

```
import { Component, OnInit, Type } from '@angular/core'; 
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <ng-container *ngIf="component">
       <ng-template [ngComponentOutlet]="component"></ng-template>
    </ng-container>
  `
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  component: Type<any>;
  ngOnInit() {
    import('./test/test.component')
    .then(module => this.component = module.TestComponent)
  }
}
```

Due to the dynamic import angular creates a separate js file with the compiled component. I tried encoding the source and doing

```
import('data:text/javascript...').then(...)
```

Yielding "module not found" error. Declaring a wildcard module

```
declare module 'data:text*';
```

Placated the IDE (VSCode in my case), but typescript still throws an error on transpilation, as typescript turns `import` into `require`. I tried different combinations of module and moduleResolution properties in tsconfig, fruitlessly. All while importing a simple test module from a data URI in javascript seems to work just fine.
Therefore, I tried putting it into an eval, the import itself worked, but the rest didn't, which, after tinkering with webpack for a while, made sense.
I modified the source to just declare the class and call angular theta functions to register the component, removing pushing to webpackJsonp and calls to `__webpack_require__.r` and `__webpack_require__.d`, and exporting the defined class. After employing more hacks (using global variables) to fix some scope problems, it worked. But then I realized there's no need to use `import` at all, if I'm `eval`-ing I might as well eval the whole thing. I did that, assigning the component class to a variable instead of exporting it, and it also worked.

**So, in the end, my approach:**

1. Dynamically import the component and build the project to get the
   compiled js.
2. Modify the sources: remove pushing to webpackJsonp, calls to `__webpack_require__.r` and `__webpack_require__.d`, assign the component class to a variable.
3. `eval` the modified source.

This works (at least for the simple components I've tried so far) but seems rather hacky and brittle. Is there a better approach?

Comment: Why not just store the classes you need to add to the dashboard as strings and use Angular's component factory to load the concrete implementation of the class and add them to the appropriate view container?

Comment: Not sure if I got you right, correct me if I'm wrong: you mean define the classes as a part of the angular application, then use resolveComponentFactory to create a component given its class, fetching it by name from some map? that's what we had before, now we need for the entire class to come from the outside, for it to never have been part of the original app.

Comment: That's correct. I don't quite understand your requirements for it to "never have been part of the original app". That seems problematic at best.

Comment: Definitely problematic, but yeah. We have a component library and dozens of projects based on it. Dashboard is part of the library and the idea is that people working on end projects can create widgets and those widgets can be shared across the other projects, without rebuilding the core library each time or bloating it.

Comment: You might take a look at: https://itnext.io/how-to-easily-reuse-components-across-projects-and-repositories-fa73f8ba2a83

Comment: thanks, I'll take a look